# Filter multiple html tables with JS

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, filtering

I'm working on a page with large multiple tables in Html.
To filter them I found and adapted this script that filter for every cell of the table:

```js
<script>
function searchtable() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  th = table.getElementsByTagName("th");

  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    if (!tr[i].classList.contains('header')) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td"),
      match = false;
      for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
        if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          match = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!match) {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem here is that the code work only in the first table of the page and not in the others.
I'd prefer to NOT repeat the script personalizing for every and each table.
Do you have any suggestion on how to personalize the script to look up in multiple tables?

Edit:
Do you know any different script that do the same thing?

Comment: To be honest, this is why we invented models. If you would have the data the table contains inside an object or an array or such, you could just fitler the array using array methods and then just rerender the table. But on topic, you can parametrize everything, so your function takes in the 'myInput' and 'myTable' ids: `function searchTable( tableId ) {}` and then just an event with the correct id for each table.

Comment: @Shilly  I'll try and study the array methods. Unfortunately I can't do it now. I really appreciate your suggestion (both the use of array methods and the use of ids). Do you have any more suggestion?

Comment: Are you trying to learn javascript or do you need working code? I have a solution, but you won't recognise your code in it anymore.

Comment: @Shilly actually right now I need working code, yet I try always to learn from myself (mostly my errors) and from the help I find from the community. Every help is always appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to explain most parts I've changed. In the end the code itsself is a bit shorter, but a tiny bit more complicated. If I made assumptions that aren't correct, let me know. (For example, I'm assuming the 'header' class is only atatched to `<tr>` elements inside the `<thead>` who contains `<th> elements)`

```js
var searchTable = function searchTable(table, input) {
    // Since we bound the input, we can use input.value to get the current words typed into the input.
    var filter = input.value,
      // A table has both a thead and a tbody.
      // By only selecting the tr nodes from the body, we can remove the entire 'check if this is a header tr logic of `tr.classList.contains('header')`
      // Keep in mind that querySelector returns a nodeList, so if we want to use array methods, we need to covnert it into a real array.
      // The original code uses getElementsByTagName, which return a LIVE nodeList, watch out for this difference.
      rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr'));
    rows.forEach(function(row) {
      // Since we don't care in which cell the fitler is contained, we can just check the innerHTML of the entire row.
      // This will only fail if the filter typed into the inputs is either 'tr' or 'td'
      var hide = (row.innerHTML.indexOf(filter) === -1);
      // The alternative is actually checking each cell, but this makes the script take longer:
      // var hide = !Array.prototype.slice.call( row.querySelectorAll('td') ).some(function( cell ) {
      //     return (cell.innerHTML.indexOf( filter ) !== -1);
      // });
      if (hide) row.classList.add('gone');
      else if (row.classList.contains('gone')) row.classList.remove('gone');
    });
  },
  // helper function that we can use to bind the searchTable function to any table and input we want
  // We add an onchange event listener, passing it a bound version of searchTable.
  bindSearch = function bindSearch(tableID, inputID) {
    var input = document.querySelector(inputID),
      table = document.querySelector(tableID);
    if (table && input) input.addEventListener('change', searchTable.bind(null, table, input));
    else alert('Table or input does not exist.');
  };
// We can add as many individual inputs / tables as we want by just calling bindSearch with the right ids.
bindSearch('#table1', '#input1');
bindSearch('#table2', '#input2');
```

```css
.gone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1">
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header 1</th>
      <th>header 2</th>
      <th>header 3</th>
      <th>header 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1-1: foo</td>
      <td>Cell 1-2: bar</td>
      <td>Cell 1-3: baz</td>
      <td>Cell 1-4: foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 2-1: apples</td>
      <td>Cell 2-2: cherries</td>
      <td>Cell 2-3: bananas</td>
      <td>Cell 2-4: foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 3-1: cars</td>
      <td>Cell 3-2: bar</td>
      <td>Cell 3-3: planes</td>
      <td>Cell 3-4: apples</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 4-1: baz</td>
      <td>Cell 4-2: 2017</td>
      <td>Cell 4-3: 2010</td>
      <td>Cell 4-4: 2001</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 5-1: cars</td>
      <td>Cell 5-2: 2017</td>
      <td>Cell 5-3: foo</td>
      <td>Cell 5-4: undefined</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="input2">
<table id="table2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header 1</th>
      <th>header 2</th>
      <th>header 3</th>
      <th>header 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1-1: foo</td>
      <td>Cell 1-2: bar</td>
      <td>Cell 1-3: baz</td>
      <td>Cell 1-4: foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 2-1: apples</td>
      <td>Cell 2-2: cherries</td>
      <td>Cell 2-3: bananas</td>
      <td>Cell 2-4: foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 3-1: cars</td>
      <td>Cell 3-2: bar</td>
      <td>Cell 3-3: planes</td>
      <td>Cell 3-4: apples</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 4-1: baz</td>
      <td>Cell 4-2: 2017</td>
      <td>Cell 4-3: 2010</td>
      <td>Cell 4-4: 2001</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 5-1: cars</td>
      <td>Cell 5-2: 2017</td>
      <td>Cell 5-3: foo</td>
      <td>Cell 5-4: undefined</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Shilly ! 
Now I understand why you wrote that it would be a huge change, but your solution is actually useful for me! 
I'll use your script, but I'll also try to find why the code I posted didn't work! 
Again, thank you very much for your help and thanks to everybody who posted suggestions to help me!

Comment: I suggest to add ".toLowerCase()" to "var filter = input.value", that way you can get a not case sensitive filter.

Comment: Definately. Just showing the principles. You can update the filter logic any way it fits your app. Or even make that a parameter you bind as well, so you can use different types of filters too. :) The code to check each cell explictly, is in the comments as well.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
    <table id="table2">
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr></tr> <tr></tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

js:

```
var table1 = document.getElementById("table1");
     var table2 = document.getElementById("table2");

 searchtable(table1);
 searchtable(table2);

    function searchtable(table) {
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      th = table.getElementsByTagName("th");

      for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
        if (!tr[i].classList.contains('header')) {
          td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td"),
          match = false;
          for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
            if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              match = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          if (!match) {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This only works if all tables should be filtered at the same time, not if each table should be able to be filtered seperately. But yes, it isn't 100% clear in the OP.

Comment: you can just select you table and pass its element to the function

Comment: Hello,
thank you @BougarfaouiElhoucine, I've tried to make your version of the script at work, but it didn't work... As I tried to filter it did nothing... 
I have add the Id in every table, but it didn't work out...
Still thank you for your help!

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine Do you think I should also add multiple input instead of a single MyInput? Also, my input form is: <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="searchtable()" placeholder="Cerca nella tabella">

Comment: `onkeyup="searchtable()"' don't use it you have to pass the table element as an argument